# Use out parameter with System.Servicemodel.ClientBase<>.ChannelBase<> EndInvoke

Tags: c#, invoke, out

[This is the official page of the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DOTNET/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1.channelbase-1.endinvoke?view=netcore-1.0) and I need to use an 'out' parameter as an argument, I guess. I have a method like this:

```
bool GetInfo(out List<foo> bar);
```

How can I use an out parameter without changing the method that I invoke? I really don't want to return a Set of bool and List in this case.

So far, I have tried to use it like this:

```
EndInvoke("GetInfo", new object[] { out bar }, ...);
EndInvoke("GetInfo", new object[] { bar }, ...);
EndInvoke("GetInfo", new object[] { }, ...);
EndInvoke("GetInfo", null, ...);
List<foo> bar = (List<foo>)EndInvoke("GetInfo", new object[] { bar }, ...);
```

but nothing really makes sense and the out bar inside the object array obviously doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you just ignore the out parameter. This is my current working solution:

```
public bool GetInfo(out List<foo> bar) {
   bar = new List<foo>();
   object[] args = new object[] { bar };
   IAsyncResult result = BeginInvoke("GetInfo", args, null, null);
   EndInvoke("GetInfo", args, result);
   bar = (List<foo>)args[0];
   return true;
}
```

And the Invokes call uses the GetInfo method from the interface line given in the question. They are 2 separate methods using the same name, so if anyone sees this and thinks it could help them, don't get confused by it.